# How to unit test location provider by Robolectric?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

There are a lot of good docs regard unit testing location such as [Android - Robolectric - Unit testing request location updates (LocationManager)](http://ckarthik17-tech.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-robolectric-unit-testing.html) but unfortunately didn't find anything regard location provider. Since I'm new to Robolectric I still have no clear insight how it works. Any idea would be appreciated.

Following code is a method I have in my activity. I display a cardView if this method returns false otherwise it is invisible. So I actually want to test visibility of this view but before this I need to mock location provider to return what I want. This is the thing that I'm looking for in first step. Thanks

```
private boolean isLocationEnabled()
    {
        int locationMode = 0;
        String locationProviders;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            try
            {
                locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

            }
            catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e)
            {
                Logger.logException(e);
            }
            return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
        }
        else
        {
            locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robolectric allows you to call into the `Settings` class and set values:

```
Settings.Secure.putString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED, "locationProvider");
```

Put what you want in there and it should return what you've set in the tests.

Comment: wow, awesome I didn't know that. This is my sample for those who are looking: `Settings.Secure.putInt(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY);`

Comment: Great! Thanks. This also worked for enabling my app to handle Android notifications from unit tests with Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS and the package name of my unit tests

Comment: perfect Thanks for the this answer