# How can I create a Location in an android Unit-Test?

Tags: android, junit

I want to create a Location in an android Unit-Test using JUnit 4.

with 
Location loc = new Location(...)
loc is null.

How can I create a location?

As I understood I have to include the Location in the build.gradle dependencies using
testCompile '...'
but I can't find what to include.

Can you help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried RoboElectric? Here is a [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260337/how-to-unit-test-location-provider-by-robolectric)

Comment: You are unit-testing *on the development machine* using pure JUnit (i.e. no on device-test)? That won't work, the compile-time android libraries are mostly stubs.

Answer (score 0):

In your module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1"
    ...
}
```

Your test class has to contain the following:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LocationTest {
    ...
}
```

And that should be it.